# android call Fragment from another fragment onclick button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I m beginner to Android. I'm trying to pass value from one fragment to another fragment. But I've found no correct code for that .. so please, can anybody write the correct code for it. I also tried FragmentTransaction, But its not working. So please help me.
thank u..

Comment: Check documentation (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: @lbrahim Mohamed Check out my answer and try to pass value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example which explains the standard way of passing data between fragments http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/handle-onlistitemclick-of-listfragment.html

Answer (score 0):

You can send a Bundle to one Fragment to another Fragment as

```
fragment.setArguments(BundlObj);
```

and get them in another fragment as

```
Bundle b = this.getArguments();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below to add values in `Fragment`

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
TestFragment llf = new TestFragment();
Bundle m_bundle = new Bundle();
m_bundle.putString("Key", <yourValue>);
llf.setArguments(m_bundle);
ft.replace(R.id.fragmentswitcherframe, llf);
ft.commit();
```

Get the value on another `Fragment` as below:

```
m_buBundle = this.getArguments();
String Val = m_buBundle.getString("Key");
```